# Get Date From Google Custom Search API

Tags: api, getdate

How i can get date data like that google search. Is it possible to get it?
I never found it in google custom search API. The second picture i post is only snippet which got date and some description about it. The first picture from google search news and the second is google custom search

[image: Google Search]

[image: Google Custom Search API]

Answer (score 1):

The following API request returns metadata, like published time, only if it is mentioned in its HTML source.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=APIkey&cx=CustomSearchEngineID&q=rambo
```

And refer to the "metatags" section 
 [image]

And *Voila!*

[image]

[image]Hope that helps :)

Comment: i have meta tags, but didn't get tag for 'published_time'