# Google custom search results published date

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

The published date of the results can be displayed on Google search in a browser by using `&as_qdr=y15`. Example [Link](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pala%20jewellers%20cannon%20park%20coventry&oq=pala%20jewellers%20cannon&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57.9950j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&as_qdr=y15)

[image]

I need to get this information on the google custom search API

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=KEY&q=pala%20jewellers%20cannon%20park%20coventry
```

The API pulls the `article:published_time` when available on the webpage but this not available for all the pages so [Google also estimates a page date based on features of the page such as dates in the title and URL](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data).

How to get Google estimated page date from the Google Custom Search API?

Answer (score 0):

The Custom Search API returns `metadata` of a page only if it is mentioned in its HTML source. You could have a look at my answer to [Get Date From Google Custom Search API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53315150/10351455).

The date displayed in the browser might be the day Google discovered and indexed that page. Or it could be the output of a smart-scraping of the page (i.e. by looking for keywords like "`last updated`" or "`published on`" in the content of the page).